# configure postfix so emails will send

Tags: networking, email, postfix

I am trying to use postfix simply to allow my blog to send emails, I don't need anything fancy like webmail.  All I want it to do is send me messages to my gmail or google apps accounts.

I've tried to send a test message using mailutils and the PHP "mail" function.  Logs report:

```
Apr 20 03:28:07 vultr postfix/qmgr[5680]: 4FD1D2BB10: from=<xxx@xxx>, size=350, nrcpt=1 (queue active)  
Apr 20 03:28:07 vultr postfix/smtp[8359]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c05::1b]:25: Network is unreachable  
Apr 20 03:28:37 vultr postfix/smtp[8359]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.70.27]:25: Connection timed out   
Apr 20 03:28:37 vultr postfix/smtp[8359]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400c:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable  
Apr 20 03:28:37 vultr postfix/smtp[8359]: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable  
Apr 20 03:29:07 vultr postfix/smtp[8359]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.141.26]:25: Connection timed out  
Apr 20 03:29:07 vultr postfix/smtp[8359]: 4FD1D2BB10: to=<xxx@xxx.xxx>, relay=none, delay=2694, delays=2634/0.01/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.141.26]:25: Connection timed out)
```

I have replaced actual email addresses with "xxx" but they are correct.

I have the same problem with sending to another address that is not hosted by google:

```
Apr 20 03:24:11 vultr postfix/smtp[7528]: connect to mailgate3.unl.edu[129.93.2.76]:25: Connection timed out  
Apr 20 03:24:41 vultr postfix/smtp[7528]: connect to mailgate4.unl.edu[129.93.88.70]:25: Connection timed out  
Apr 20 03:25:11 vultr postfix/smtp[7528]: connect to mailgate7.dfw.rackspace.its-sys.unl.edu[104.130.124.23]:25: Connection timed out  
Apr 20 03:25:41 vultr postfix/smtp[7528]: connect to mailgate6.unl.edu[129.93.88.28]:25: Connection timed out  
Apr 20 03:25:41 vultr postfix/smtp[7528]: 3DE6E2BB12: to=<xxx@unl.edu>, relay=none, delay=1576, delays=1423/0.01/154/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mailgate6.unl.edu[129.93.88.28]:25: Connection timed out)
```

what gives?  Why can't I connect to any outgoing site?  ufw is disabled, there is no running firewall unless ubuntu automatically enables one without asking when installing postfix?

Comment: It may be that your internet provider is blocking outbound traffic on port 25 from their network (to fight spam etc.) Especially if you're in dhcp network. If you are - even if you'll get your port 25 open for outbound traffic, your mails may be rejected on many servers (again, for spam fighting)